# ¿Como crear un archivo completamente nuevo en Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Estoy tratando de hacer algo muy sencillo: crear un archivo completamente nuevo en una de mis carpetas de mi app de Laravel. Lo estoy intentando hacer desde un `Observer`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

use App\Template;

class TemplateObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the template "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Template  $template
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(Template $template)
    {
        Storage::disk('local')->put('example.txt', 'Contents');
    }
}
```

Ya que son pruebas preliminares, no importa el titulo ni el contenido del archivo. En `filesystems.php` tengo esta configuracion

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],
```

Entiendo que con la actual configuracion y codigo, deberia aparecer un archivo `example.txt` en mi carpeta app.

Pero por alguna extraña razon, el archivo no se crea. No obtengo ningun error, ningun mensaje, nada. Simplemente no se crea. Algo importante a mencionar es que la aplicacion de Laravel esta corriendo dentro de un contenedor.

¿Que me falta hacer o que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿No aparece en el directorio `storage/app/`? No me queda claro si estás mirando ahí o en el directorio `app/` en la base de tu proyecto

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ pensaba que apareceria en el directorio app, el de hasta afuera (por asi decirlo). En efecto si aparece en ese directorio, muchas gracias! Si quieres dejar una respuesta la marcare como aceptada. Es raro que la documentacion de Laravel no explique muy bien las configuraciones del filesystems.php

Comment: @KennyBarrera La documentación lo dice. Además, literalmente allí te lo dice `storage_path('app')` se traduce en `storage/app`.

Comment: @JonatanLavado la documentacion no dice nada hahaha. "Example configurations for each supported driver are included in the configuration file so you can modify the configuration to reflect your storage preferences and credentials." Literalmente dice: guiese con los ejemplos.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer sobre `helpers`, especificamente [storage_path()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-storage-path)

Comment: @JonatanLavado Pues claro, ya que porloscerros nos ilumino, yo tambien busque los helpers y aprendi algo nuevo el dia de hoy. A lo que voy es que no es obvio y Laravel deberia ser un poco mas claro en la documentacion. Gracias a todos por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

A la pregunta:

> ¿Como crear un archivo completamente nuevo en Laravel?

Respondería:
Está bien como lo estás haciendo. Usar la facade Storage, a mi modo de ver, es la forma de hacerlo *"a la manera Laravel"*.
Como vimos en los comentarios bajo la pregunta, la confusión se dió por el directorio de destino de ese archivo.

Si miramos en la documentación File Storage [The Local Driver](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-local-driver), veremos que (en español) dice algo así:

> Cuando se utiliza el driver `local`, todas las operaciones de archivo son relativas al directorio `root` definido en el archivo de configuración `filesystems`. De forma predeterminada, este valor se establece en el directorio de `storage/app`. Por lo tanto, el siguiente método escribiría en `storage/app/example.txt`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::disk('local')->put('example.txt', 'Contents');
```

Y ese directorio `root` definido en el archivo de configuración `filesystems` es el que muestras en la pregunta:

```
'disks' => [
    //..
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],
]
```

Para el caso se usa el helper [storage_path()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-storage-path) añadiéndole un subdirectorio `app`, que devolverá la ruta absoluta al directorio de `storage/app` de tu proyecto.

---

Ahora si lo que quieres es crear el archivo en el subdirectorio `app/` en la base de tu proyecto, puedes crearte un disco en el archivo `filesystems.php`, pero usando el helper [app_path()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-app-path) para asignar el directorio `root` de ese disco:

```
'disks' => [
    //..
    'app' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => app_path(),
    ],
]
```

Y lo usas de manera similar a como lo hiciste con el disco `local`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::disk('app')->put('example.txt', 'Contents');
```